# Is a laptop cooler really effective and useful?

Tags: laptop, cooling

Is a laptop cooler really effective and useful?

I have a Dell laptop - it doesn't have any problems but was wondering if a laptop cooler would be beneficial in any way?

Some example coolers: http://www.smcinternational.in/index.php?option=com_virtuemart&page=shop.browse&category_id=48&Itemid=101

Comment: I have a Dell m1530 and without a cooler it runs at 89C consistently.  With a laptop cooler I'm running more at 50-60C.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, a laptop cooler can help.  Running hot can lead to performance problems and shorter equipment life.  I don't have first hand experience with heat problems in an actual laptop (yet).  An older laptop I have does tend to run very hot (too hot to touch on the underside) if I don't use a cooler, but with the cooler it stays reasonably cool.

The most recent example of equipment problems due to excessive heat I've seen was in a wireless router I have.   A few months ago some stuff was put next to it,  blocking its ventilation.  It started having problems - frequent drop outs, for example.  When I checked it out, I found it was extremely hot to the touch.  I moved it to a place where it cannot be surrounded with stuff and it has operated without problem since.

A side benefit is that the [laptop cooler I have](http://www.targus.com/us/productdetail.aspx?regionId=7&sku=AWE19US1&PageName=Cooling&productCategoryId=12&bucketTypeId=0&searchedTerms=&navlevel1=products&cp=&bannertxt=Cooling%20for%20Laptops) sits under my laptop and allows me to change the angle of the system.  This makes for better ergonomics.  (Already having eye problems and CTS, I appreciate that.)

Comment: yeah. remember that it also implies in your battery health, since Li-Ion batteries hate heat.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, but the effectiveness varies by the design of the cooler.  See this [review of the Cooler Master NotePal U3](http://www.overclockersclub.com/reviews/notepal_u3/4.htm) at Overclockers Club for a comparison of laptop coolers; all of them yielded lower temperatures than a laptop being placed directly on a desk.

Comment: But I don't overclock my laptop. So what extra benefit I will see if I buy a cooler for laptop. What is benefit to buy and use laptop cooler even if I'm not facing any heating problem with my laptop.

Comment: The life of the system could be extended by keeping overall system temperatures down.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it also depends on were you are located. I used to live in a very "warm" country and it made a huge difference for me in durability when I started to use coolers.